# How to format dialogue about a playing video?

Tags: dialogue, formatting

So let's say I have characters A and B who are chatting about a video that Character A recorded of themselves. In between their chatting, the dialogue of the video can also be heard, for example:

> "Hey look at this... why isn't it working?" said Character A.
>
> "You didn't press play," said Character B.
>
> The video started to play, "Hi everyone, my name is Character A and this is..." said Character A in the video, taking the audience through a tour of the house.
>
> "You sound really stupid Character A."
>
> "Yeah well maybe you should do it next time then," said Character A, getting touchy.

So essentially I have treated the video as another character, even though it's a recording of Character A. **Are there any format guidelines for this sort of thing?** In the case where there is something important in the video, I need the content to come through as well (both audio and visuals), if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this works well. As far as I know, there are no style guidelines for this, so you can do this however you want.

I would say that you should use the screen as a 'character,' so have it say "the screen said as it suddenly came to life. Character A was in the video..." more or less. But as I said, there are no set guidelines on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need to worry about prefacing the speech in the video, as it'll become obvious in the dialogue tag following it as well as the different tone in the dialogue itself.

I would possibly cut it off at a natural place where you can place a comma, but that's just a suggestion from my writing style so take it with a grain of salt. I would also use ellipsis sparingly, but again, a personal style decision.

> "Hey, look at this. Why isn't it working?" John said, passing the remote to Sam.
>
> "You didn't press play," Sam said, snapping up the remote.
>
> "Hi everyone! My name is John, and this is my house," the video began as John took his viewers through a tour of the house room by room.
>
> "You sound really stupid, John."
>
> "Yeah, well maybe you should do it next time then," John said, becoming red in the cheeks.